# Intercepting TCP packets of genymotion android emulator

Tags: android, genymotion, burp, thick-client

I am pentesting android application. I used burpsuite and configured genymotion emulated android to use my host as proxy. Installed CA certificates on android (android api < 24). Everything went well and I was able to intercept and manipulate http/https traffic of the application.

However, I noticed that not all the data being exchanged between the application and the server is being intercepted, so I ran tcpdump through adb shell and found out that the application exchange tcp packets that contain the missing data through special api with special port(src:37966 & dst:25050). I explored the data and found no means of encryption  (I could read pcap file plain text in wireshark).

I googled and found out that this is called "thick client application" and it is not aware of the global proxy setting on the emulated device.

Is there a chance that transmitted tcp packets which I captured are http exchanged over custom ports and thus burpsuite ignore them? **In this case how can I configure burpsuite to capture those data to modify it on the fly?** I am aware I can use invisible proxy setting in burpsuite but how can I forward that specific port 37966 in my emulated android to burpsuite proxy on my host machine and still be able to intercept normal http/https traffic?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

- I unpacked the apk file and looked into semi-human readable source code. Found out that client do serilization using [kyro](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo).

**Question**

- Can I deserialize the packets in my .pcap file to be able to read the data?

Comment: Please stay focused, on Stackoverflow you should only ask one question per post, now you have to that are totally unrelated (capture traffic in Burp and read Kyro data from pcap).